# XSLT: Remove duplicate nodes based on name attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the below input XML which needs to be transformed with an xslt

Input Xml:

```
<result>
    <circuit>MX123456</circuit>
    <psaresult>
        <Live_Alarms>
            <diagnosis>
                <utr>xxx</utr>
                <dtr>xxx</dtr>
                <text />
                <site>xxx</site>
                <address />
                <tech_type />
                <end />
                <network_type>xxx</network_type>
            </diagnosis>
            <Alarms>
                <alarmId>463</alarmId>
                <cct>xxx</cct>
                <eventTime>12/05/11 09:21:21</eventTime>
                <clearTime />
                <problemCode>xxxx</problemCode>
                <problemText>xxxx</problemText>
                <equipmentName>xxx</equipmentName>
                <unit>xxx</unit>
                <rcKey>xxx</rcKey>
                <category>xxx</category>
                <rootCause>xxxx</rootCause>
            </Alarms>
            <Alarms>
                <alarmId>464</alarmId>
                <cct>xxx</cct>
                <eventTime>12/05/11 09:21:22</eventTime>
                <clearTime />
                <problemCode>yyyy</problemCode>
                <problemText>yyyy</problemText>
                <equipmentName>yyyy</equipmentName>
                <unit>yyyy</unit>
                <rcKey>yyyy</rcKey>
                <category>yyyy</category>
                <rootCause>yyyy</rootCause>
            </Alarms>
        </Live_Alarms>
    </psaresult>
</result>
```

Expected output:

```
<result>
    <circuit>MX123456</circuit>
    <psaresult>
        <Live_Alarms>
            <psadiagnosis>
                <utr>xxx</utr>
                <dtr>xxx</dtr>
                <text />
                <site>xxx</site>
                <address />
                <tech_type />
                <end />
                <network_type>xxx</network_type>
            </psadiagnosis>
            <Alarms>
                <alarmId>463</alarmId>
                <cct>xxx</cct>
                <eventTime>12/05/11 09:21:21</eventTime>
                <clearTime />
                <problemCode>xxxx</problemCode>
                <problemText>xxxx</problemText>
                <equipmentName>xxx</equipmentName>
                <unit>xxx</unit>
                <rcKey>xxx</rcKey>
                <category>xxx</category>
                <rootCause>xxxx</rootCause>
            </Alarms>
        </Live_Alarms>
    </psaresult>
</result>
```

**Note**: Ony the first `Alarms` node is needed like what `SelectSinglenode` does and all others needed to be truncated from the output. Can you please advise how this can be achieved from an xslt?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution that is based on the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern -- the overriding of the identity rule.

Comment: Explanations and link are also provided.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is the canonical identity rule - based solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Alarms[position() >1]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<result>
    <circuit>MX123456</circuit>
    <psaresult>
        <Live_Alarms>
            <diagnosis>
                <utr>xxx</utr>
                <dtr>xxx</dtr>
                <text />
                <site>xxx</site>
                <address />
                <tech_type />
                <end />
                <network_type>xxx</network_type>
            </diagnosis>
            <Alarms>
                <alarmId>463</alarmId>
                <cct>xxx</cct>
                <eventTime>12/05/11 09:21:21</eventTime>
                <clearTime />
                <problemCode>xxxx</problemCode>
                <problemText>xxxx</problemText>
                <equipmentName>xxx</equipmentName>
                <unit>xxx</unit>
                <rcKey>xxx</rcKey>
                <category>xxx</category>
                <rootCause>xxxx</rootCause>
            </Alarms>
            <Alarms>
                <alarmId>464</alarmId>
                <cct>xxx</cct>
                <eventTime>12/05/11 09:21:22</eventTime>
                <clearTime />
                <problemCode>yyyy</problemCode>
                <problemText>yyyy</problemText>
                <equipmentName>yyyy</equipmentName>
                <unit>yyyy</unit>
                <rcKey>yyyy</rcKey>
                <category>yyyy</category>
                <rootCause>yyyy</rootCause>
            </Alarms>
        </Live_Alarms>
    </psaresult>
</result>
```

**exactly the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<result>
   <circuit>MX123456</circuit>
   <psaresult>
      <Live_Alarms>
         <diagnosis>
            <utr>xxx</utr>
            <dtr>xxx</dtr>
            <text/>
            <site>xxx</site>
            <address/>
            <tech_type/>
            <end/>
            <network_type>xxx</network_type>
         </diagnosis>
         <Alarms>
            <alarmId>463</alarmId>
            <cct>xxx</cct>
            <eventTime>12/05/11 09:21:21</eventTime>
            <clearTime/>
            <problemCode>xxxx</problemCode>
            <problemText>xxxx</problemText>
            <equipmentName>xxx</equipmentName>
            <unit>xxx</unit>
            <rcKey>xxx</rcKey>
            <category>xxx</category>
            <rootCause>xxxx</rootCause>
         </Alarms>
      </Live_Alarms>
   </psaresult>
</result>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **The [identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** (template) copies every node "as-is".
2. **There is a single template overriding the identity rule**. It matches any `Alarms` element that isn't the first `Alarms` child of its parent. This template has no body -- effectively discarding any such matched element from being copied into the output.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(self::Alarms)] | Alarms[1]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result>
    <circuit>MX123456</circuit>
    <psaresult>
        <Live_Alarms>
            <diagnosis>
                <utr>xxx</utr>
                <dtr>xxx</dtr>
                <text />
                <site>xxx</site>
                <address />
                <tech_type />
                <end />
                <network_type>xxx</network_type>
            </diagnosis>
            <Alarms>
                <alarmId>463</alarmId>
                <cct>xxx</cct>
                <eventTime>12/05/11 09:21:21</eventTime>
                <clearTime />
                <problemCode>xxxx</problemCode>
                <problemText>xxxx</problemText>
                <equipmentName>xxx</equipmentName>
                <unit>xxx</unit>
                <rcKey>xxx</rcKey>
                <category>xxx</category>
                <rootCause>xxxx</rootCause>
            </Alarms>


        </Live_Alarms>
    </psaresult>

</result>
```

Comment: I happened to use this and it worked <xsl:copy-of select="//Live_Alarms/Alarms[1]"/>. Thanks. Any other comments on this whether I need to modify this?

Comment: @Jaisal, It will copy 1st `Alarms` node.